# saveGame function not writing to file

Tags: c++, console-application

For some reason my saveGame function is not writing anything to the PlayerData.txt file when I go to save the game. It was working fine earlier but it has since stopped working.
This is my Game.cpp file:

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "EnemyEncounter.h"
#include "LootEncounter.h"
#include <fstream>

Game::Game()
{
    IsRunning = false;
    CurrentTurn = 0;
    ThePlayer = Player();


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int range = 100 - 1 + 1;
        int roll = rand() % range + 1;

        if (roll >= 80) {

            int gold = rand() % 100 + 1;
            int exp = rand() % (100 - 20 + 1) + 20;
            Map.push_back(new LootEncounter(gold, exp));
        }

        else {
            Map.push_back(new EnemyEncounter("Goblin", 10, 5, 20, 20));
        }
    }

    CurrentEncounter = Map[0];
}

void Game::MainMenu()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "-----------Text Adventure Game-----------\n";
    cout << "----------------Main Menu----------------\n\n";
    cout << "1) New Game\n";
    cout << "2) Load Game\n";
    cout << "0) Exit Game\n";
    int option;
    cin >> option;

    switch (option) {
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Starting Game...\n";

        cout << "The player is level: " << ThePlayer.GetLevel() << "\n";

        cout << "Press ENTER key to begin.\n";
        cin.ignore();
        StartGame();
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    case 0:
        system("cls");
        exit(0);
        break;
    }

}

void Game::StartGame()
{
    using namespace std;

    IsRunning = true;

    while (IsRunning) {
        system("cls");
        TakeTurn();
    }
}

void Game::TakeTurn()
{
    using namespace std;

    CurrentTurn++;

    ofstream saveFile("PlayerData.txt");

    string PlayerData = "PlayerData.txt";

    cout << CurrentTurn << " Taking a turn...\n";

    if (CurrentEncounter->GetType() == EncounterType::Monster) {
        cout << CurrentEncounter->GetState();

        EnemyEncounter* enc = dynamic_cast<EnemyEncounter*>(CurrentEncounter);

        while (!enc->IsCompleted) {
            // do stuff to the enemy
            cout << ThePlayer.GetStatus();
            cout << enc->GetEnemy().GetStatus();
            cout << "What would you like to do?\n";
            cout << "A) Attack\n";
            cout << "R) Run\n";
            cout << "S) Save Game\n";
            cout << "X) Exit\n";
            char option;
            cin >> option;

            // TODO: Fix multi character inputs from choosing multiple options.
            option = tolower(option);

            switch (option) {
            case 'a':
                // attack the enemy
                enc->GetEnemy().TakeDamage(ThePlayer.GetDamage());
                break;
            case 'r':
                // run away
                cout << "You attempt to run away!\n";
                cout << "No luck! You are stuck!\n";
                enc->SetComplete();
                break;
            case 's':
                // TODO savefile not writing for some reason
                saveGame(ThePlayer, PlayerData);
                if (saveGame(ThePlayer, PlayerData)) {
                    cout << "Game saved successfully.\n";
                }
                else {
                    cout << "Failed to save game.\n";
                }
                cin.ignore();
                cin.get();
                return;
                break;
            case 'x':
                system("cls");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:

                cout << "Invalid option, please choose again.\n";
                break;
            }
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore();

                if (!enc->GetEnemy().IsAlive()) {
                    Reward reward = enc->GetReward();

                    ThePlayer.GainExperience(reward.Experience);
                    ThePlayer.IncreaseGold(reward.Gold);

                    cout << "You gain: " << reward.Experience << " experience and " << reward.Gold << " gold.\n";

                    enc->SetComplete();
                    cout << "Press ENTER key to continue.\n";
                    cin.get();
                }
                else {
                    int damage = enc->GetEnemy().GetDamage();
                    cout << "The " << enc->GetEnemy().GetName() << " hits you for " << damage << "!\n";
                    ThePlayer.TakeDamage(damage);
                    cout << ThePlayer.GetStatus();
                    cout << "Press ENTER key to continue.\n";
                    cin.get();
                }
        }

        if (CurrentTurn < 10) {
            CurrentEncounter = Map[CurrentTurn];
        }
    }
    else if (CurrentEncounter->GetType() == EncounterType::Default) {
        cout << CurrentEncounter->GetState();

        if (CurrentTurn < 10) {
            CurrentEncounter = Map[CurrentTurn];
        }
    }
    else if (CurrentEncounter->GetType() == EncounterType::Loot) {
        cout << CurrentEncounter->GetState();

        LootEncounter* enc = dynamic_cast<LootEncounter*>(CurrentEncounter);

        Reward reward = enc->GetReward();

        ThePlayer.GainExperience(reward.Experience);
        ThePlayer.IncreaseGold(reward.Gold);

        cout << ThePlayer.GetStatus();

        // advance the turn
        if (CurrentTurn < 10) {
            CurrentEncounter = Map[CurrentTurn];
        }

        cout << "\nPress ENTER to continue\n";
        cin.get();
    }
    else if (CurrentEncounter->GetType() == EncounterType::Puzzle) {
    }
    else {
        cout << "The encounter here is invalid.\n";
    }



    if (!ThePlayer.IsAlive()) {
        cout << "The player has died\n";
        IsRunning = false;
    }

    if (CurrentTurn >= 10) {
        IsRunning = false;
    }
}

bool saveGame(Player& player, const std::string& PlayerData)
{
    std::ofstream saveFile(PlayerData);
    if (saveFile.is_open())
    {
        saveFile << "Level: " << player.GetLevel() << std::endl;
        saveFile << "Gold: " << player.GetGold() << std::endl;
        saveFile << "Experience: " << player.GetExperience() << std::endl;

        saveFile.close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried several different ways to write to the file but I must have messed something up along the way that I'm not catching onto.

Comment: In `Game::TakeTurn`, you do: `ofstream saveFile("PlayerData.txt");` When this goes out-of-scope (at the end of `Game::TakeTurn`), it probably clobbers the data saved by `saveGame`. This appears to be a cut-and-paste error (it is defined but not used)--I'd remove it. Also, note that for `case 's':` you call `saveGame` _twice_

Comment: "It was working fine earlier but it has since stopped working." - so compare your current version with an earlier version via your source control software...

Comment: You are opening the file `PlayerData.txt` twice for writing, once inside `Game::TakeTurn` and once inside `savegame`. Is this intentional?